# How can I add an event listener on one area of the page?

Tags: javascript

I have an event listener on page 1

```
window.addEventListener("keydown")
```

It's causing me issues where another event listener "keydown" in a dialog on that page 1 is conflicting with the window event listener.

So dialog event listener
Page event listener

When I add text to the dialog, the page picks up that keydown. I don't want that. I can't add stopPropagation to the page then the dialog won't get the backspace.

What should I do? Can I replace the window. part to something more specific?

Comment: *Can I replace the window. part to something more specific?* - yes, but you will have to focus that area

Comment: Don't ask multiple versions of the same problem. Edit the existing question to improve it.